# Airports, points of interest and cities Auto complete

Tags: database, api, autocomplete

I'm currently working on a travel booking application.

I have two questions related to the same topic.

I need to know where sites like Priceline, Expedia or cheapoair get their autocomplete search data from? Such as Airports, points of interest and city's- states. Do these sites go off the google places API for their search autocomplete?

I was thinking about getting this data using google places autocomplete. Would this be a wise way to go about it? Or would I be better of finding a JSON file with all this data and store it on my own server and query the JSON file directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try out this?
- https://community.algolia.com/places/
- https://demos.algolia.com/geo-search-demo/ [Search for airports]
- and check the guide that goes with the demo https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/geo-search/geo-search-overview

Having your own database would give you more flexibility. Also, users would query you data so there'd probably be less search with no results (with google search, users could type queries that are not related to any of your content).

Does that make sense?

Comment: Hi Jean, So I checked out the algolia api. Seems pretty good. I'm going to except this answer. Do you know of any accurate open source databases that I can host on my own server?